# Android -How to Get a View From a Parent Class to Show in an Inherited Class

Tags: android, kotlin, inheritance, view

I have a Parent class that has an imageView in it. Another class inherits from that parent class. How can I get the other class to show the imageView from the parent class in its (other class) hierarchy?

FYI I have several common views, methods, and properties that I use in a bunch of other classes. To keep my code clean I added everything common in a parent class and let the other classes inherit and use what's needed.

Parent:

```
open class ParentActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var parentBinding: ActivityParent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        parentBinding = ActivityParent.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(parentBinding.root)

        parentBinding.profileImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_icon)
    }

    fun showImageViewFromParentInAnyOtherInheritedClass() {

        // I tried these in different combinations but nada

        parentBinding.profileImageView.bringToFront()

        parentBinding.profileImageView.requestLayout()
        parentBinding.profileImageView.invalidate()

        parentBaseBinding.profileImageView.translationZ = 90f
        parentBaseBinding.profileImageView.elevation = 4f
    }
}
```

Class that Inherits from Parent:

```
class AnotherActivity : ParentActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityAnother

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityAnother.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        showImageViewFromParentInAnyOtherInheritedClass()

        binding.usernameTextView.text = "pink lemonade"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can’t do this. An Activity can only have one root view. When you call setContentView in the child class, you are replacing whatever you set with setContentView in the parent class. What exactly do you want to accomplish? You could inflate some views in the superclass and then add them into your layout in the subclass. Or you could do the inverse, which probably makes more sense. But what possibly makes the most sense would be to build everything you need in a single class. If there are things you need in multiple activities you can use global functions to set them up.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for the info. I had a feeling that it wasn't possible but I didn't know the child's `setContentView` replaced the parent. Would I be able to use an `interface`, programmatically create the views and accompanying methods, then use that inside each child class? For example all of my classes that makes a network call eventually show/hides a progressBar. To me it doesn't make sense to keeping adding it and the logic to show/hide it to each individual class. Creating a base/parent class (my question) or interface that creates it and its methods, then the other classes can use that

Comment: "**You could inflate some views in the superclass and then add them into your layout in the subclass.**" How do I do that? Btw I'm learning Android now, I'm a novice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from the iOS world where I do everything programmatically. In iOS programmatic views are very versatile. That being said I decided to take the same approach here. I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do things in the Android world but this has worked so far.

1- I created an `Interface`

2- Inside that interface I programmatically created the view(s), properties, and methods I need my child activities to use.

3- Inside the parent class I call the interface thus giving me access to the everything in step 2

4- When my child vcs inherit the parent class they automatically have access to everything in the parent class and the interface.

Steps 1 & 2:

```
interface MyInterface {

    fun createProgrammaticImageView(context: Context): ImageView {

        val imageView = AppCompatImageView(context).apply {
            this.id = View.generateViewId()
            this.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_icon)
        }

        imageView.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        
        return imageView
    }

    fun hideProfileImageView(imageView: ImageView?, hide: Boolean) {
        imageView?.alpha = if(hide) 0.0f else 1.0f
    }
}
```

Step 3:

```
open class ParentActivity: AppCompatActivity(), MyInterface {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent)
    }

    var profileImageView: ImageView? = null

    fun addProfileImageViewTo(rootLayout: ConstraintLayout) {

        val imageView = createProgrammaticImageView(this) //<------- Code from MyInterface

        imageView.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
            topToTop = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID
            startToStart = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID
            endToEnd = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID
            bottomToBottom = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID
            width = 250
            height = 250
        }

        rootLayout.addView(imageView)

        profileImageView = imageView
    }

    // *** Other methods and properties inside this class that the child classes will need access to ***
}
```

Child Class:

```
class AnotherActivity: ParentActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAnother

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityAnother.inflate(layoutInflater)

        addProfileImageViewTo(binding.root) //<--------- Code from the Parent Class

        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.usernameTextView.text = "pink lemonade"

        binding.someButton.setOnClickListener {
            logicToHideOrShowProfileImageView()
        }
    }

    private var hideImageView = false

    private fun logicToHideOrShowProfileImageView() {
        // ... some logic to toggle hideImageView to true/false

        hideProfileImageView(profileImageView, hideImageView) //<----- Code from MyInterface
    }
}
```

Again I'm coming from the iOS world so if this is the wrong way to do this in Android, can someone please explain why and give me a better answer. This took hours to figure out but it seems to work and keeps the code in the child class or any other class that inherits from the parent easier to maintain. **For simplicity sakes this is a very watered down version.**

Comment: I think this is OK. XML is there to help make things easier but you don't have to use it. Jetpack Compose is Android's new code-based UI system, where you directly create your UI in Kotlin, but it is a different paradigm of view creation because everything is created reactively instead of imperatively telling already-created views what to do.. By the way, there's no reason to call `setContentView` in the parent class since you'll be replacing it.

Comment: I do think ConstraintLayouts are particularly clunky to work with programmatically. I don't know how your method of doing it could be adapted to work in various different layouts where other views might depend on where it's placed, but maybe you're not planning to use it that way.

Comment: Usually you can set a view's visibility by setting the extension property `view.isVisible` to true or false. It will still take up space in the layout. So for this particular case, what you've built here seems like overkill because you're not saving any steps by having the interface.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for the look over. I still need to learn SwiftUI but I don't want to overwhelm myself. Right now I want to learn Android using XML then after I learn SwiftUI I'll bounce back to Jetpack Compose. `ConstraintLayouts` reminds me of iOS' `Anchors`, they're very similar. Relative and LinearLayouts are what I'm unfamiliar with. From my understanding Google was pushing for ConstraintLayouts over the other 2 the same way they're pushing Kotlin over Java.

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of creating parent Activities. [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). For instance, the functions in your interface don't reference each other, so it could all just be a couple of global functions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I was going to use `visibility` but I figured alpha would be easier to understand for the next person who comes along, runs into a problem similar to mines, and finds the post. When I first encountered `View.GONE` vs `View.INVISIBLE` it took me a while to wrap my head around the difference. Especially coming from an iOS world

Comment: I tried to make it as simple as possible. For eg. in the actual app the reason I'm using the Parent and inheritance is because I can control the back button in the parent and use the same steps in the children without having to replicate the same exact code. If a user is posting, I disable the back button, and then enable it afterwards. Having the able/disable back button logic in 1 class, then any child can use it. I also have a `Job` coroutine `lifecycleScope` (per your comment to my other question) in the parent. Any child that needs it can use it instead recreating the same one over again

Comment: Anyway, the way I would build this: (1) Create XML layout of just your ImageView with the drawable icon and layout params that assume it will be in a ConstraintLayout. (2) For each activity layout that needs it, [`<include>`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) the layout as a one-liner in the XML. (3) You can create global (possibly extension) functions that work with ImageViews or whatever you're doing with them that might be common between multiple activities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253763/discussion-between-lance-samaria-and-tenfour04).